# image as submit button

Tags: image, form-submit

I have a simple form with a submit button. I would like to use the submit button using an image something like,

```
<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="images/submit.gif" HEIGHT="30" WIDTH="173" BORDER="0" ALT="Submit Form">
```

How can I use the image as submit button? Then what I want to change in jquery initialisation?

```
<form action='#' id='freeForm' method='post' autocomplete="off">
<a> 
<input style='border: none' type='submit' value='Submit' /> 
</a>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$("#freeForm").submit(function()
    {
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: `<input type="image" name="submitbtn" src="images/submit.gif">`

Comment: @mack: You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery isn't necessary, as an image button [already submits a form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
<form>
    <input type="image" src="foo.png" />
</form>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/AkR95/

Answer (score 1):

u can do some thing like this

```
$("#image").onclick(function()
    {
$("#freeForm").submit();
    });
```

`#image` is the id of element containing your image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<input type="submit" value="Enter" name="submit" style="background:url('/imgBG.jpg') no-repeat;width:100;height:50;border:none;"/>
```